# Is ADD A,5 allowed?

Tags: x86-16, assembly

```
ADD A, 5
```

Now A and 5 both are immediate. Is it allowed in Assembly Language?

Comment: If they are both immediate, then where does the result go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this intel syntax flavor? What is A?

Usually `A` is an address (effectively a variable). **If so, it is allowed**. Look for the definition of A (e.g. a DD pseudo instruction with that label)

If a is the hex number (usually written as 0Ah, %0x0a though) of course, it can't work

Comment: Soooo. Would the downvoter kindly explain the reason why this needs to be downvoted?

Comment: Maybe because you dared to not answer the question in the literal sense? (I upvoted you)

Comment: @drhirsch Thx. "If so, it is allowed". I'll bold the direct answer

Answer (score 3):

If `A` is really an immediate (defined like `A EQU 7` or similar) this is not allowed in x86. Generally instructions with immediate target operands are not allowed, as the result would be discarded.

More likely you are making a wrong assumption "Now A and 5 both are immediate" in your question and sehe's explanation is right.